# Вопрос по WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce, php

Здравствуйте! Такой вопрос: при создании в WooCommerce заказа ему дается порядковый номер (например, 120, 125 и т.д.).

Мне необходимо изменить как-то алгоритм, чтобы номера заказов начинались с 600. Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли такое?

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE wp_posts AUTO_INCREMENT = 600
```